# trouble accurately finding an average time

Tags: java, time

I'm working on a project for my university assignment and I'm struggling to accurately find the average song duration for my program.

I'm entering the duration of 3:33 three times and getting the input from an arrayList, which should return the result of 3:33. However, the result I'm getting is 3:19.

I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong, I've tried changing things here and there but still get the same result.

```
public void display()
{
    String durationTemp = "";
    String durationStr = "";
    double durationDbl = 0;
    double durationTotal = 0;
    double durationAvg = 0;

    double time = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;


    if (songCount > 0)
    {
        displayHeading();

        for (int i = 0; i < songCount; i++)
        {
        displayTextArea.append(songsArrayList.get(i).toString());
        appendLine();

        durationTemp = songsArrayList.get(i).getDuration();
        durationStr = durationTemp.replace(':','.');
        durationDbl = Double.parseDouble(durationStr);
        durationTotal = durationTotal + durationDbl;
        durationAvg = durationTotal / songCount;
        }

    time = (int)(100 * durationAvg);
    minutes = (int)(time/100);
    seconds = (int)(60 * (time%100));

    displayTextArea.append("average song duration: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }

    else
    {
        displayError("No songs have been entered");
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you multiply by 100 then divide by 100? what relevance does `100` have with time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.33 minutes equals 199.8 seconds,
whereas 3:33 equals 213 seconds.
You can't (or shouldn't) just replace `:` by `.`

There's no point in calculating
durationAvg = durationTotal / songCount;
while you're inside the for loop. Do it once, outside.